# Unable to serialize a class using State server mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have an asp.net web api application :

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>
     <sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="1500" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr" />
  </system.web>
```

**In Controller**

```
ITaigaTimeSheet itaiga;

public TaigaApiController()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["taigaclass"] == null)
    {
        string mail = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["User_mail"];
        HttpContext.Current.Session["taigaclass"] = new TaigaTimeSheet(mail);
    }
    itaiga = (TaigaTimeSheet)HttpContext.Current.Session["taigaclass"];
}
```

**In BLL**

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class TaigaTimeSheet : ITaigaTimeSheet
{
    ITaigaClient client = null;
    Itimesheet SabCruder = null;
    ICrud<vw_sab_client_affaire> cruder = null;
    List<Project> taigaProjets = new List<Project>();
    List<Member> taigaMembers = new List<Member>();
    List<vw_sab_client_affaire> client_affaires = new List<vw_sab_client_affaire>();
    List<vw_sab_client_affaire> All_client_affaires = new List<vw_sab_client_affaire>();
    public TaigaTimeSheet()
    {
        client = new TaigaClient();
        client.GetMembersAndProjects(ref taigaProjets, ref taigaMembers);
        SabCruder = new Timesheet();
        cruder = new Crud<vw_sab_client_affaire>("stblinked");
        client_affaires = cruder.GetAll().ToList();
        All_client_affaires = cruder.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

I need to store an instance of class `TaigaTimeSheet` as a session variable using `StateServer` mode.

But I get this exception :

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

So I need to know :

1. How can I fix this?
2. What is the reason of this error?

Thanks,

Comment: @Downvoter explain your reasons

Comment: what is  ITaigaClient client?

Comment: Error basically says there is some non serializable objects with in your TiageTiemSheet class which are not permitted for serilization.....I suggest you add non serializable attribute to members you dont need...

Comment: I do not see any problem with your question...dont know why the downvotes...I compensate by upvoting it :)

Comment: @Viru ITaigaClient,ITaigaClient , ICrud and Itimesheet   are interface , Project and member are structs and vw_sab_client_affaire is entity framework class

Comment: ok I knew theryare interface...what I wanted to ask was is that web proxy instance? and maybe web proxy instance is not allowed for serialization

Comment: for testing purpose, mark everthing as nonserializable except taigaProjects and taigaMembers and see if this error goes away?

Comment: @Viru thank you very much, plz post your response as an answer

Comment: Glad it worked...Posted it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purpose, mark everthing as nonserializable except taigaProjects and taigaMembers.

Error basically says there is some non serializable objects with in your TiageTiemSheet class which are not permitted for serilization.I suggest you add non serializable attribute to members you dont need.